# Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: vb.net, arrays

At the line `If aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1) Then the

> Index was outside the bounds of the
>   array.

error appears. Can't identify why would it be outside array's bounds.
Basically trying to compare Last Names to sort the records and place em back into list box.

A student record looks like this:
FirstName[space]LastName[space]Major[space]Telephone[space]Email[space]GPA

Example: Johny Cake E201 6666666666 me@me.com 1.0

```
 Private Sub btnAscending_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAscending.Click
        ''#load all students into array
        Dim arySort(numberOfRecords) As String
        Dim aryTemp(6) As String
        Dim aryTemp2(6) As String
        For i = 0 To numberOfRecords - 1
            arySort(i) = lstListBox.Items(i)
        Next
        Dim temp As String ''#holds temporary record
        Dim k As Integer
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 2
            aryTemp = Split(arySort(i), " ")
            For k = i + 1 To arySort.Length - 1
                aryTemp2 = Split(arySort(k), " ")
                If aryTemp(1) < aryTemp2(1) Then ''# index of 1 refers to last name of a split string
                    temp = arySort(k)
                    arySort(k) = arySort(i)
                    arySort(i) = temp
                End If
            Next
        Next
        lstListBox.Items.Clear()
        numberOfRecords = 0
        isLoaded = False
        For i = 0 To arySort.Length - 1
            lstListBox.Items.Add(arySort(i))
            numberOfRecords += 1
        Next
        currentRecord = 0
        isLoaded = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Will your algorithm work if someone's last name contains a space?

Comment: Not really, because the split() uses " " as the separator so if someone had a space in their last name it they would end up with 3 names perhaps.

Comment: I find names to be tough... if there is a space in the last name is one of them a middle name?  Or what if there is a second first name (also a middle name).  In a single string unless there is only one space you can't guarantee where the last name starts.  This should be done with a 2d array and last names should be stored separately.

Comment: There's no middle name input available in my GUI. Only First Name and Last Name. I'm planning on enforcing some kind of validation to prevent user having space in either of those input fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in VB.NET are zero-based, so your code is declaring one too many items for each array.  As written, arySort will contain one item for each record in your ListBox, *plus* one extra, empty item.  That will cause one of your aryTemp2 = Split(arySort(k), " ") calls to split on Nothing, which will leave you without any enough items in the aryTemp2 array to do the comparison with aryTemp.

Corrected code:

```
Dim arySort(numberOfRecords - 1) As String
Dim aryTemp(5) As String
Dim aryTemp2(5) As String
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're comparing against the second item in `aryTemp2` (the item at index `1`), however `aryTemp2` contains either 1 or 0 elements. Looks like you're expecting `Split(arySort(k), " ")` to return an array containing more elements than it actually is. You should check the dimensions of the array before comparing into it, or verify that `arySort(k)` contains at least one space (to ensure that `arySort2` will have at least two elements in it).

Comment: The dimensions of aryTemp and aryTemp2 are correct. The student data consists of 6 items: first name, last name, major, telephone, email and gpa. 6 items, and aryTemp(6) means that the Ubound of the array is 6 aka 0-6 so even 7 items. So unless it is whining about an extra space, I have no idea.

Comment: wait, so this data is built with a space delimiter.  What if my major is "Computer Sciences?"  How would that be handled?

Comment: The majors are represented by a combination of a letter and 3 numbers so inputs such as Computer Sciences wouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

try `If aryTemp(aryTemp.Length - 1) < aryTemp2(aryTemp2.Length - 1) Then` but it does follow the assumption that last names can't have spaces.  If this is not the case then the code could be built out more to handle that situation.

Comment: Trim(), or perhaps change the separator from " " to "," or anything else more appropriate?

Comment: Can you change the separator to an array?  Is is easy to make a multi-dimensional array before the data gets here?

Comment: For now the student data(single string with spaces consisting in total of 6 items about student) will be stored in an array and Split() into another array with " " as the separator.

Comment: This doesn't compare the Last Names just the last elements which are GPAs(the last element in the string) in this case

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Visual Studio 2008 or later, you can make this **much** simpler:

```
Private Sub btnAscending_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAscending.Click
    Dim arySort = lstListBox.Items.OrderBy(Function(s) s.Split(" "c)(1)).ToArray()
    lstListBox.Clear()
    lstListBox.AddRange(arySort)
    currentRecord = 0
    isLoaded = True
End Sub
```

I wouldn't suggest turning it in, because it's way outside of what your professor expects of this assignment.  Also, it has the same issue as your original code of not checking to make sure there really is a space in the string to split on. But think of it as what you should be shooting for.

Comment: Just saying that this still haven't resolved my issue because this is not allowed to be used in my source.

Comment: @Johnny - look at my 2nd to last sentence.